# how would i set up the images in this array

Tags: jquery, html, arrays

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.vut').tooltipster();
    $('.vut').hover(function(){
        $(this).tooltipster('content', $('<div><img src="famulan'+$(this).children()[1].innerHTML+'.png" ></div>'));
        $(this).tooltipster('show');
    });
  });
```

would i add them to this script or would i set up another jquery or script file?
i already have the image folder 
i just need to route them to one of the selectors through my tooltip
this way when i hover over them they create an image preview
and this is a periodic table btdubs
so any tips on how to organize them would be great

Comment: What is "them"? It seems like the beginning of your question got lost.

Comment: Also please share your html, we have no idea what `.vut` children are